# How to get better error VirtualBox in ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I'm using 64-bit ArchLinux host, Windows 10 guest. I've done installing the `virtualbox`, running `dkms autoinstall`, `modprobing vboxdrv`, and installing the guest OS (Windows 10 64-bit). But after I restart the host, I could not start the guest VM anymore, it stuck with message "Starting virtual machine.." and "Starting virtual machine.. (2/2)". The terminal itself (after running `virtualbox` command) doesn't give any meaningful error message, just one line:

```
Qt Warning: libpng warning: iCCP known incorrect sRGB profile
```

The screenshot

[image: virtualbox stuck starting]

How to get better error message, to find out the problem?

```
$ lsmod | igrep vbox
vboxdrv               393216  1

$ ps aux| igrep virtualbox
xxx       8026  0.0  0.0  11948  2312 pts/2    S+   22:16   0:00 grep --color=auto -i --color=auto virtualbox
xxx       8035  0.4  0.4 1182776 78900 pts/0   Sl+  21:50   0:06 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox
xxx       8051  0.1  0.0 155136  9448 ?        S    21:50   0:02 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxXPCOMIPCD
xxx       8057  0.3  0.1 632772 19376 ?        Sl   21:50   0:05 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC --auto-shutdown
xxx      10613  0.5  1.6 1952644 276184 ?      Sl   21:51   0:08 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --comment Win10 --startvm 94b63dc8-b586-418e-bd29-d8d5834918f7 --no-startvm-errormsgbox

$ uname -a
Linux xxxyyy 4.1.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 11 15:41:14 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ pacman -Q |igrep virtualbox
virtualbox 5.0.2-1
virtualbox-host-dkms 5.0.2-1
virtualbox-host-modules 5.0.2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could find the problem on the `Virtualbox VMs/MachineName/Logs/VBox.log`. In this case the pulseaudio stucks (because 2 conflicting soundcards), by changing the default `Host Audio Driver` from `PulseAudio` to `ALSA`, the VM now can start normally.